# Express [413 too large] with QuillJS image

Tags: forms, express, quill

I am trying to use QuillJS to let the user write a rich text, and then store it as JSON to display later on. There are 2 of these rich text areas in a single form, and may include images. QuillJS encodes images as base64 strings, and my POST request results in 413 by Express.

I have tried to change the limits by adding express json parameters, even trying extreme numbers.

```
// app.js
//----------------------------------------------------
// Middlewares
//----------------------------------------------------
app.use(express.json({limit: '2000mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true, limit:'2000mb'}));
```

Even this did not help and I think it is not logical to let these parameters with such values.

I tried with json and urlencoded enctypes. When I tried to post with multipart/form, `req.body` was empty.

```
// My html page (pugJS)

form(enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded', action='/editor/page', 
     method='POST', onsubmit='return addContent()')

.form-control
        label Content-1
        div#toolbar
        div#editor
        input#content(name='content', type='text',  hidden)
```

addContent() function that runs before form submit simply changes `input#content`'s value with `JSON.stringify(#editor.getContents())`

I want to be able to store two quill content in a single database row, to display later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem few hours before @argo mentioned and I did it that way. So I wanted to post little bit of detail to the solution. I have been also guided by a github issue but can't seem to find the link again, in case I find it I will edit the post and add it.

```
// Quill - EN content
var quillEn = new Quill('#editor-en', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});

// set custom image handler
quillEn.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('image', () => {
  selectLocalImage(quillEn);
});

// create fake input to upload image to quill
function selectLocalImage(editor) {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png, image/jpeg')
  input.click();

  // Listen upload local image and save to server
  input.onchange = () => {
    const file = input.files[0];
    saveImageToServer(editor, file);
  };
}

// upload image to server
function saveImageToServer(editor, file) {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('image', file);

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/api/page/upload_image', true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      // this is callback data: url
      const url = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data;
      insertToEditor(editor, url);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(fd);
}

// manipulate quill to replace b64 image with uploaded image
function insertToEditor(editor, url) {
  // push image url to rich editor.
  const range = editor.getSelection();
  editor.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', url.toString());
}
```

In the backend where you POST image, you must return json as `{ data: FullUrlToImg }` with 200 response, if you want to change your status to 201 or something else, don't forget to update it in `saveImageToServer` function.

So to summarize, you set custom image handler for your quill editor, you post the image to server as soon as user chooses to insert, then you replace the URL with your uploaded image in the editor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to this would be to overwrite the image upload function and then save the image in Amazon S3 or some cloud server. Then you paste it inside the editor as `<img src="http://uploaded-image-url">` This would solve your problem of maximum memory issue.